# AWS AppConfig Amazon EventBridge extension

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-event-bridge, aws-app-config

Ref - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appconfig/latest/userguide/working-with-appconfig-extensions-about-predefined-notification-eventbridge.html

Based on the above documentation, by enabling EventBrdige extension for AWS AppConfig, we can get notifications from AppConfig on actions like ON_DEPLOYMENT_START, ON_DEPLOYMENT_COMPLETE.

I am trying to implement a pub/sub type architecture using EventBridge and SNS Topics. The idea is that services will request for latest configuration from App Config once they receive a ON_DEPLOYMENT_COMPLETE event. It seems straightforward for 'AllAtOnce' deployment strategy that we will get a notification when the deployment is complete.

I would like to know how the notifications work with other strategies like 'AppConfig.Linear50PercentEvery30Seconds' where we incrementally roll out deployments to a certain percentage of hosts.

Can somebody help me with this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In the strategies like `AppConfig.Linear50PercentEvery30Seconds` or `AppConfig.Canary10Percent20Minutes`, we get only one complete notification, same as `AllAtOnce`

This is not specifically described, but  there are sentences like "If no alarms are received in this time, the *deployment is complete*." in the [doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appconfig/latest/userguide/appconfig-creating-deployment-strategy.html#appconfig-creating-deployment-strategy-predefined)

It seems there is no way to get notified when each growth factor ends.

Comment: Yeah..wanted to find out if there is anything out there I am not aware of. Thanks for the response!